# Samba config gui tool doesn't run

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, windows-7, samba

I am trying to access my windows 7 pc from my ubuntu laptop running 11.10 64bit but I cannot open the system-config-samba gui.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/filesharing-between-windows-and-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/). My windows 7 pc sees the laptop no problem at all.

Comment: Can you add some information to your question? I'm not sure what you mean by "samba gui"

Comment: Ive been following a tutorial i found on the net and it shows a samba server configuration box that I have to select preferences from then server settings from but if I try and open samba(as shown) I get asked for my ubuntu password then nothing.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/04/connect-ubuntu-11-04-and-windows-systems-via-sambapart-one/

Comment: I know that is for 11.04 but i found one for 11.10 on the same site.

Comment: Heres the link  http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/filesharing-between-windows-and-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Comment: Prob best I just re-install windows 7 on my laptop it just works!

Comment: Well, please add some detail to your question, or at least ask how to set up file sharing instead of following random blog posts from the internet publishing incorrect information. :)

Comment: mark as closed, resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install glade and python-glade. It is most easy using synaptic. i/ve have had the same problem and now it works fine.

```
sudo apt-get install glade
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
sudo install gksu system-config-samba
```

then run:

```
 gksu system-config-samba
```